# Word 2013 repeating section content control filtering

Tags: c#, xpath, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I am developing a Word 2013 document generation tool, on Visual Studio 2012.

I have a Word docx template generated by C# code, with content controls.

I have another application which extracts XML data from a database into a customXML, and updates the content controls data binding xpath strings to map nodes in the customXML, and display data in the resulting word document.

For example, I have the following custom XML :

```xml
<Configurations>
  <Configuration internalName="AAA"/>
  <Configuration internalName="BBB"/>
</Configurations>
```

The "Configuration" element is mapped to the repeating section content control.

I want to display only the configuration "AAA". Which is the right xPath string to do that?

Here is the C# code :

```
ccRepSec.XMLMapping.SetMapping("//Configuration[@InternalName='AAA']");
```

The XPath string seems to be correct, but the filtering does not work. The two configuration elements are displayed in the repeated section.

Any solution?

Comment: Did both of the repeating sections display AAA? 

Generally, there is no way to omit or otherwise filter certain data from a repeating section, without a VBA macro to do so. It's a little unclear why you would add a repeating section to only show the first item. Unless you are reading the data out of the .docx later, I would advise not adding additional data into the XML. Even then, I would question using the .docx as a 'container', basically, for data that is not being displayed in the doc itself.